# Is there way I could go back to my old Xcode after I missed up the flutter app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter

I have messed up my Xcode for iOS flutter. It was asking for camera deployment iOS 10.0 at least. I had 8.0 but I pressed fix on the yellow yield then it changed the code which gave me all of this errors.

I have tried copy and pasta my back up Xcode and did not work.
Pods/Development Pods/ camera/ open311_s /ios/ .symlinks/camera/ iOS/ classes/ Cameraplugin.m  I missed up this class inside Xcode.

Xcode's output:
↳

```
 /Users/zuhairhallak/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camer
    a-0.4.3+2/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m:651:45: warning: unused variable
    'discoverySession' [-Wunused-variable]
              AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession * discoverySession =
              [AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession
                                                ^
    /Users/zuhairhallak/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camer
    a-0.4.3+2/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m:662:40: warning: unused variable
    'devices' [-Wunused-variable]
              NSArray<AVCaptureDevice *> * devices = discoverySession.devices;
                                           ^
    /Users/zuhairhallak/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camer
    a-0.4.3+2/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m:667:51: error: use of undeclared
    identifier 'devices'
            [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: devices.count];
                                                      ^
    /Users/zuhairhallak/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camer
    a-0.4.3+2/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m:668:7: warning: collection expression
    type 'AVCaptureDevice *' may not respond to
    'countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:'
          for (AVCaptureDevice *device in device) {
          ^                               ~~~~~~
    /Users/zuhairhallak/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camer
    a-0.4.3+2/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m:693:19: warning: unused variable 'cam'
    [-Wunused-variable]
              FLTCam *cam = [[FLTCam alloc] initWithCameraName:cameraName
                      ^
    /Users/zuhairhallak/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camer
    a-0.4.3+2/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m:706:54: error: use of undeclared
    identifier 'cam'
          int64_t textureId = [_registry registerTexture:cam];
                                                         ^
    /Users/zuhairhallak/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camer
    a-0.4.3+2/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m:707:17: error: use of undeclared
    identifier 'cam'
          _camera = cam;
                    ^
    /Users/zuhairhallak/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camer
    a-0.4.3+2/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m:708:7: error: use of undeclared
    identifier 'cam'
          cam.onFrameAvailable = ^{
          ^
    /Users/zuhairhallak/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camer
    a-0.4.3+2/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m:716:38: error: use of undeclared
    identifier 'cam'
          [eventChannel setStreamHandler:cam];
                                         ^
    /Users/zuhairhallak/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camer
    a-0.4.3+2/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m:717:7: error: use of undeclared
    identifier 'cam'
          cam.eventChannel = eventChannel;
          ^
    /Users/zuhairhallak/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camer
    a-0.4.3+2/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m:725:8: error: use of undeclared
    identifier 'cam'
          [cam start];
           ^
    4 warnings and 7 errors generated.
```

I was able to run the app fine but now I can't run it. How can I fix Xcode for flutter app.

Comment: Did you try a ```flutter clean``` and a manual ```pod install``` ? this might fix your issue, I don't think it's an Xcode issue at all. Also check your signing configuration.

Comment: I tried to do pod install manual and did not work.

Comment: Thank you so much. I found out why.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I have messed up the class for camera plugin that was provided by flutter using its dependences. You can find that in pubspec.yaml. I have deleted the dependence of the camera and the app was able to run. Thats should fix the problem. Copy cameraPlugin.m from flutter plugin and delete the code messed up then put the new one.

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m#L25